# debugging c library called from python on windows

Tags: python, c, eclipse, debugging, cython

I work with c code that is compiled to a static library in windows (using mingw alias gcc 4.6.2) and connected to python (2.7.5, win32 MSC v.1500) via cython. Cython is used to feed the library with simulation data prepared in python (numpy arrays), and to read back the result into python for later evaluation.

The simulation works fine, only issue was structure padding due to the different compilers (resolved by packing c structs).

Now I wonder if this simulation setup could be used to debug the c code itself, i.e. without writing the data handling code also in c. Eclipse is used for the lib development so that would be the preferred environment for debugging. Is there any way to achieve this?